# Generators of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ such that for some **uncountable** family $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{F}$ we have

- $X = \bigcup \mathcal{A}$,
- for every countable subfamily $\mathcal A_0 \subset \mathcal{A}$ the union 
  $\bigcup \mathcal{A}_0$ is not $X$.

Is it possible to show (in ZFC) that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is strictly smaller than $\mathcal{F}$?

Some relevant references would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P_{< \omega_1}(\omega_1)$  on $\omega_1$ and $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal P_{< \omega_1}(\omega_1)$.
Clearly $\bigcup A = \omega_1$, $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) =  \mathcal P_{< \omega_1}(\omega_1)$ and for any countable $\mathcal A_0 \subseteq \mathcal A$, we have that $\bigcup \mathcal A_0$ is a countable union of countable subsets of $\omega_1$ and hence not cofinal in (in particular not equal to) $\omega_1$.

Comment: I see, this would have worked if $\mathcal{A}$ comprised pairwise disjoint sets, right?

Comment: @user32141 No, take $\mathcal A = \{ \{\alpha\} \mid \alpha < \omega_1 \}$ -- the set of all singletons of $\mathcal P_{< \omega_1}(\omega_1)$. It still generates all of $\mathcal P_{< \omega_1}(\omega_1)$,  consists of disjoint sets and poses a counterexample to your refined claim.